# Does T-Mobile network allow incoming UDP packets?

Tags: android, udp, 3g

Short version: **Does the T-Mobile network allow incoming UDP packets?**

Longer version:

I'm writing a small test app that connects two Androids over a mobile network. It works over LAN but not over 3g.

Most carriers block incoming TCP connections over their networks, Does the same restriction apply to incoming UDP?

Comment: It sounds like you're not implementing [STUN](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389) (or some similar solution to the same problem) properly.

Comment: I'm using the standard Java classes and not using STUN or anything in particular. Any tips for Android/Java? The RFC is a bit dense...

Comment: You'll need a third party server for the two endpoints to "rendezvous" on. They'll both need to use the third party server to establish the direct connection. It's not simple.

Comment: Yes I've been learning that. There is no easy answer to direct communication over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been testing UDP port forwarding on 3G from [T-Mobile Slovakia (Deutsche Telekom)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovak_Telekom) and found that it's not possible. They are using [Symmetric NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which will prevent you from communicating endpoints between two peers because one peer's incoming port will depend on another peer's IP address. I wrote a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139611/273348).

I've not yet had problems with [O2 Slovakia (Telefónica)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telef%C3%B3nica_Slovakia) in this regard.

EDIT: This may be irrelevant now given that the question is 5 months old, but since you mentioned building a test app, the best tutorial on NAT traversal I've found is IMO [this one](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/).